# UserControl content not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I'm creating a simple UWP application for myself and stuck with lack of understanding of how binding and all that stuff works. Don't know how to explain it better So I created a simple example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/744dc688d0663a3c14b7a2fc424316f8

The program has a list of selectable items on main screen. I can select several items, press a button and program will show new floating panel, with selected items (And I do further management of these items in my original program). I want this panel to be separate control because my MainPage is already overfilled with code.

The problem is. When I click on the button first time - it works as I expect. But then, when I change selected items and click button again, it shows panel with items from first selection.

My question is - how to do make it work? I have a feeling that it has to be something with `INotifyPropertyChanged` but cannot understand it.

And I also would be glad to hear the overall recommendations. I'm not c# developer. I'm actually sys. admin but I know a little of python and I learned Delphi 7 in university. So I'm kind of learning c# in process of creation of this application.

**UPD:** If I change line 28 of `SelectedItemsView.xaml` from

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind SelectedItems}"
```

To

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=SelectedItemsViewRoot}"
```

(and add `x:Name="SelectedItemsViewRoot"` to user control attributes). It works as needed. So new question arrives - is this correct way to do this? I though that `Binding` is kind of legacy and `x:Bind` is newer approach that should be used in new apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use `{Binding}`, but if you want to stick with `{x:Bind}`, you can do this with OneWay mode (instead of default OneTime). For example: `{x:Bind SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}`.

I strongly encourage you to read these two official tutorials:
[Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) and [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

In short, `{Binding}` is not legacy. It's actually a bit more flexible, but it's performed in runtime, while `{x:Bind}` is perfmormed at compile time, thus a bit more performant.